# What $f(R)$ models pass most of the known constraints?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, dark-matter, modified-gravity

In most papers and talks about [$f(R)$ gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1726) authors repeatedly state that the model proposed by [Starobinsky 2007](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0021364007150027)

$$
f(R)=R+\lambda\,R_{0} \bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{R^{2}}{R_{0}^{2}}\bigg)^{-n}-1\bigg]
$$

passes all or most of the known constraints.

My question is: Are there any other models which also pass all known constraints?

I am mainly concerned with models with modifications that become important for small $R$.

Comment: Can you expand more on your question? Add some links maybe.

Comment: This seems like a list-based question

Answer (score 0):

I think in general there is a wide class of models that should pass cosmological and astrophysical constraints.  The [Living Review](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2010-3) on this is a good place to look.  In section 14 they explain the basic constraints on allowed types of $f(R)$ models.  It seems like they amount to

1. $f_{,R} > 0$ and $f_{,RR}>0$ when $R>R_0$, where $R_0$ is the scalar curvature of the present universe (something like the Hubble rate squared).  This is to avoid ghosts or tachyons.
2. $f(R)$ approaches the usual GR Lagrangian for $R>R_0$, to pass local gravity constraints like solar system tests.

There is another restriction on the derivatives of $f$ to ensure the late time de Sitter phase exists and is stable.

Section 4.2 of that article also describes some viable $f(R)$ models that have noticeable infrared (or low curvature) effects.  But basically it amounts to choosing a function that satisfies the above constraints (of which there are many), and then simply checking to see if it gives the desired behavior on cosmological scales.